# For a fixed $a \in R$, determine the dimension of the subspace of $P_n(R)$ defined by ${f \in P_n (R): f(a)=0}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Here is the question: For a fixed $a \in R$, determine the dimension of the subspace of $P_n(R)$ defined by ${f \in P_n (R): f(a)=0}$.

Since $f(a) =0$, we can write $a_n x^n+ a_n-1 x^{n-1}+... a_0 x^0$=0

How do I argue that for $P_n (R)$ in this case, there are $n$ dimensions?

Comment: maybe you should clarify at first what is is $R$ and $P_n(R)$

Comment: $R$ is real number, and $P_n(R)$ is any polynomial with degree of n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What is the degree of the polynomial once you factor the root $(x-a)$ from  $f$? If $a$ is the only root, then $g(x)(x-a) = f(x)$ and $g(x)$ would be a basis.

The reason that the set $1, x, x^2, ..., x^n$ is a basis for $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ is because by definition a polynomial $p \in P_n(\mathbb{R})$ has the form: $$p(x)= a_n x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...a_0$$ thus a linear combination of the selected basis hits all vectors in the space. We need not choose this set as a basis, however. Any linearly independent set of vectors which has a length corresponding to the dimension of the space will also be a basis.

Comment: Can you specify how you would prove that it is a basis? (i.e. linearly independent?)

Comment: Sure. To show that it is linearly independent, you must show that $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}_...a_0 = 0$ only if $a_i = 0$. It is helpful to rewrite this condition as $a_n x^n = -a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+...-a_0.$ Do you see how this implies that $a_i$ must be zero?

Comment: Is it the vectors are individually unique $x^n$, $x^{n-1}$ so that the only way to equal is scalars being 0?

Comment: Yes. You can represent each $x^i$ as (0,0,..., 1,...,0) with a 1 in the i-th place. For instance if I was looking at $P_2(\mathbb{R})$, $p(x) = a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$ could instead be represented by $(a_2, a_1, a_0)$. In fact, there is a map which preserves "structure" between $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ making them equivalent in some sense. They are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Each polynomial can be wroten as $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ where you can see that {$x^i$}$_i$ is a base of $P_n$. So, $P_n$ has n+1 dimentions (note that from $0$ to n we have n+1 terms).

If $p(a)=0$ we have that p(x) = (x-a)($\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}b_ix^i$) at least, by the fundamental theorem of algebra. So, the space of this functions have n dimentions (this new sum only have n elements).